# Array of pointers to the struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, linked-list

I am coding in C a Zoo for a school project. Where there are Areas and Animals within it. We must use dynamic structures. I am trying to do the Areas and I am stuck. I am using a linked list.

### Structure

```
typedef struct area Area, *pArea;

    struct area{
       char id[10];
       int size, nadj;
       pArea prox; //for linked list

       pArea adj[3]; ///array of pointers to the struct area
    };
```

### Filling the list

```
void fill(pArea p){
    printf("ID: ");
    scanf(" %10[^\n]", p->id);
    printf("Size: ");
    scanf(" %d", &p->size);
    printf("Nadj: ");
    scanf(" %d", &p->nadj);

    if(p->nadj == 0)
        for(int i = 0; i < p->nadj; i++)
            p->adj[i] = NULL;   
    else    
           //stuck here. HELP
    }

    p->prox = NULL;
 }
```

> AreaA 500 2 AreaB AreaC

Where *AreaA* is the **id**, *500* is the **size** variable, *2* is the number of Areas (**nadj**) that will be near the AreaA, following with the areas. Now, my teacher said that the areas near the **id Area** must be stored in a array of pointers to the struct Area (**pArea adj[3]**, it must be in max 3 Areas) but I don't know how to fill that array while only using the name of the areas as they are on the above example when they are of type **struct Area** and not an array.

Comment: put some more detail so we can understand your question more better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to maintain some kind of map from area names to areas. Then

```
    for (int i = 0; i < p->nadj; i++) {
        name = read_name();
        p->adj[i] = find_area_by_name(name);
    }
```

where `find_area_by_name`, well, should do what its name suggests. Depending on the amount of areas you need to handle (and level of the class) you may implement it as simple as linear lookup, or as fancy as AVL tree.

BTW,

```
if(p->nadj == 0)
    for(int i = 0; i < p->nadj; i++)
        p->adj[i] = NULL;
```

is effectively a no-op. Since the loop is entered only when `p-nadj == 0`, it is equivalent to

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 0; i++)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Going to try it out and then I will say something @user58697